# Error starting tomcat7 server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

When I try to start the apache tomcat 7 via a command line I have this error:

```
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverManagerImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/org/hyperic/hq/appdef/server/session/ServerManagerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 10 of type [org.hyperic.hq.appdef.shared.ServiceManager]: : Error creating bean with name 'serviceManagerImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/org/hyperic/hq/appdef/server/session/ServiceManagerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 11 of type [org.hyperic.hq.measurement.shared.MeasurementManager]: : Error creating bean with name 'measurementManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementManagerImpl.measurementDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO.hibernateStringEncryptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementManagerImpl.measurementDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO.hibernateStringEncryptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceManagerImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/org/hyperic/hq/appdef/server/session/ServiceManagerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 11 of type [org.hyperic.hq.measurement.shared.MeasurementManager]: : Error creating bean with name 'measurementManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementManagerImpl.measurementDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO.hibernateStringEncryptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementManagerImpl.measurementDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO.hibernateStringEncryptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceManagerImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/org/hyperic/hq/appdef/server/session/ServiceManagerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 11 of type [org.hyperic.hq.measurement.shared.MeasurementManager]: : Error creating bean with name 'measurementManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementManagerImpl.measurementDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO.hibernateStringEncryptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementManagerImpl.measurementDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO.hibernateStringEncryptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)

    ... 123 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementManagerImpl.measurementDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO.hibernateStringEncryptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 137 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementManagerImpl.measurementDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO.hibernateStringEncryptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 149 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'measurementDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor org.hyperic.hq.measurement.server.session.MeasurementDAO.hibernateStringEncryptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)

    ... 162 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'markedStringEncryptor' while setting bean property 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markedStringEncryptor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/hq-server-5.0.2.jar!/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)

    ... 184 more
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [] suite aux erreurs précédentes
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
GRAVE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [ZeventProcessor] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Déploiement du répertoire /home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/docs de l'application web
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Déploiement du répertoire /home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/manager de l'application web
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Déploiement du répertoire /home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/host-manager de l'application web
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Déploiement du répertoire /home/stage/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/examples de l'application web
12 mars 2014 15:02:50 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 30733 ms
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Please post the app-context.xml -- every thing related to "markedStringEncryptor" is interesting in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Stack trace looks exactly as described in https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8924. Updating Spring version to 3.1.1+ should help.